# How to set color for table rows based on column value in jQuery data table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatables.I have the data like as follows

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
-----------------------
 AAA    BBB     CCC
 AAA    GGG     YYY
 BBB    ooo     LLL
```

Now in column1 for first 2 rows i have same value `AAA`.I want to apply some color to those
 rows.And then another color for third row.Like this i have 30 records.Is it possible to do this.If possible how i can do this.I am using jQuery data tables.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use the [fnRowCallback](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnRowCallback) (or newer [rowCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback)) to achieve this

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
        switch(aData[0]){
            case 'AAAA':
                $(nRow).css('color', 'red')
                break;
            case 'BBBB':
                $(nRow).css('color', 'green')
                break;
            case 'CCCC':
                $(nRow).css('color', 'blue')
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p88MP/1/)

Comment: @PSR any way there should be some bussiness logic which says what color to be applied for a value

Comment: Thanks @ArunPJohny , but I think ```return nRow ``` is required in this callback function, otherwise, datatable will raise an exception like " a node was not return by fnRowCallBack"

Comment: Please consider updating you answer as per @Herve MARTIN answer. The new API access the column data by name.

Answer (score 7):

API has recently changed, you should now use aData['Column1'] instead of aData[0]

Answer (score 3):

createdRow functionality was added in v 1.10

> This callback is executed when a TR element is created (and all TD child elements have been inserted), or registered if using a DOM source, allowing manipulation of the TR element.
>
> This is particularly useful when using deferred rendering (deferRender) or server-side processing (serverSide) so you can add events, class name information or otherwise format the row when it is created.

https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow

Example:

```
    $('#example').dataTable({
        // ...
        "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
            if ( data["column_index"] == "column_value" ) {
                $( row ).css( "background-color", "Orange" );
                $( row ).addClass( "warning" );
            }
        },
        // ...
    });
```

Comment: this worked for me but I had to specify "column_index" as the column name (string) rather than the index (int).