# highlight Datatables rows that contain same column information

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a Datatables table that i need to highlight rows that have same value in col 2 and col 3. if a row have the same 2 values highlight both of them. whats the best way to do that in Datatables.

currently i'm having a JQuery function the combine the 2 values to a single string and search tables. but its not efficient and slow and can't find duplicates if they go out of page 1.

here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/f9gs8ywt/1/

```
var data = { 
    data : [
         { id : 1, car: "toyota", order: "53421" },
         { id : 2, car: "ford", order: "53421" },
         { id : 3, car: "chevrolate", order: "13255" },
         { id : 4, car: "mazda", order: "23155" },
         { id : 5, car: "toyota", order: "51234" },
         { id : 6, car: "ford", order: "53421" },
         { id : 7, car: "BMW", order: "31312" },
         { id : 8, car: "Audi", order: "53412" },
         { id : 9, car: "toyota", order: "51234" },
         { id : 10, car: "BMW", order: "42123" },
         { id : 11, car: "Honda", order: "42153" },
         { id : 12, car: "Jeep", order: "31245" },
         { id : 13, car: "Lexus", order: "12344" },
         { id : 14, car: "toyota", order: "53421" },
         { id : 15, car: "Hyundai", order: "23411" },
         { id : 16, car: "Kia", order: "32415" },
         { id : 17, car: "toyota", order: "51234" },
         { id : 18, car: "Hyundai", order: "35123" }
     ]
 }

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    data : data.data,
    columns : [
        { data: 'id', title: 'id' },
        { data: 'car', title: 'car' },
        { data: 'order', title: 'order' },    
    ]  
})  

table.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16353735/9078716) which solves the problem by assigning CSS classes to rows based on column values.

Specifically the code uses the [fnRowCallback](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnRowCallback) (or you can use the newer [rowCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback)) as shown below:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
        // aData is the columns array, and you can get
        // the required value using the correct index
        switch(aData[0]){
            case 'toyota':
                $(nRow).css('color', 'red')
                break;
            case 'audi':
                $(nRow).css('color', 'green')
                break;
            case 'lexus':
                $(nRow).css('color', 'blue')
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There would be other ways also, I just giving you, how you can achieve by adding extra column to add class with different color to dispaly similar rows, With datatable `createdRow`

```js
var data = { data : [{ id : 1, car: "toyota", order: "53421" },    { id : 2, car: "ford", order: "53421" },    { id : 3, car: "chevrolate", order: "13255" },    { id : 4, car: "mazda", order: "23155" },  { id : 5, car: "toyota", order: "51234" },  { id : 6, car: "ford", order: "53421" },  { id : 7, car: "BMW", order: "31312" },  { id : 8, car: "Audi", order: "53412" },  { id : 9, car: "toyota", order: "51234" },  { id : 10, car: "BMW", order: "42123" },  { id : 11, car: "Honda", order: "42153" },  { id : 12, car: "Jeep", order: "31245" },  { id : 13, car: "Lexus", order: "12344" },  { id : 14, car: "toyota", order: "53421" },  { id : 15, car: "Hyundai", order: "23411" },  { id : 16, car: "Kia", order: "32415" },  { id : 17, car: "toyota", order: "51234" },  { id : 18, car: "Hyundai", order: "35123" }]};

var colors = ["red","green","blue","grey","pink","brown"];
var temp = {};
for(let i in data.data){
  if(data.data[i].car in temp){
    data.data[i].color = temp[data.data[i].car];
  }else{
    var index = getRandom(colors.length);
    var color = colors.pop();
    temp[data.data[i].car] = color;
    data.data[i].color = color;
  }
}
function getRandom(num){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
}

//console.log(data.data);

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
 data : data.data,
  columns : [
    { data: 'id', title: 'id' },
    { data: 'car', title: 'car' },
    { data: 'order', title: 'order' },    
  ],
  createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex){
    $(row).addClass(data.color);
  }
})  

table.draw();
```

```css
.red{
  color:red;
}
.gren{
  color:green;
}
.blue{
  color:blue;
}
.grey{
  color:grey;
}
.pink{
  color:pink;
}
.brown{
  color:brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.0.0/js/dataTables.rowReorder.js"></script>

<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.0.0/css/rowReorder.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="example"></table>
```

**Add more color or make it dynamic**

Answer (score 0):

Either way you will have to compare `car` and `order` values to all other rows, since this is the criteria for marking a duplicate. Perhaps there are clever ways, but you could let a function `map` data and add a `className` if any duplicate exists:

```
function getData(data) {
  return data.data.map(function(d) {
    for (var i=0,l=data.data.length; i<l; i++) {
      var c = data.data[i];
      if (d.car == c.car && d.order == c.order && d.id != c.id) {
        d.className = 'highlight';
        return d
      }
    }
    return d
  })
}
```

It simply compare each item with all other items, if a match is found it adds a `className` to the item and jumps out of the loop.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   data : getData(data),
   columns : [
     { data: 'id', title: 'id' },
     { data: 'car', title: 'car' },
     { data: 'order', title: 'order' },    
   ],
   rowCallback: function(node, data) {
     if (data.className) $(node).addClass(data.className)
   }
})
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/0kdd3894/**